# Boot from USB option not avalible Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: boot, usb, windows-7, asus, bios

I am trying to install Windows 7 on my ASUS K55V laptop running UBUNTU 14.10 but I cannot seem to find Boot from USB option in BIOS. There are only two options to boot form, Hard disk and DVD Drive. There is not even an option to Add Bootable device or anything as such.
Help!!

Comment: Many new computers see a USB flash drive as just another hard drive.
Can you set your flash drive as first hard drive in BIOS?

Comment: I cannot see my flash drive anywhere in BIOS. And if I try to make my Hard Drive as the first boot option, still doesn't recognise the flash drive anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn secure boot off before an Asus X200 would boot from USB.  Things worked normally after that.

---

The secure boot option is in the UEFI settings (BIOS), so if your machine is not a UEFI machine, it does not even exist.

Comment: How can I turn secure Boot Off?